# Python Flask executable file

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask and building a simple web app. I want to create an executable file from the app that I built. Is this possible?

So, instead of the user having to go to their command prompt, type `set FLASK_APP=web-app.py` and `flask run`, is it possible to create an executable file from the Python script that does this for you?

Comment: You could package it as a Docker container, assuming you deploy it to a system that runs Docker

Comment: It's also possible for you to create a powershell or bash script that runs the python command to launch the flask server so the user can just launch those files.